# AttributeError: module 'open3d' has no attribute 'PointCloud'

Tags: python, point-clouds, open3d

I'm trying to an example code in my vsc editor. However, I got the AttributeError: module 'open3d' has no attribute 'PointCloud'error. I looked how to fix this problem but none of those are worked. Looking for any help. I'm using Win10 and Python 3.8. Thanks in advance

```
import open3d as o3d
import numpy as np

pc_array = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5]], dtype=np.float32)
print(pc_array)

pc = o3d.PointCloud()
pc.points = o3d.Vector3dVector(pc_array)
print(pc)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](http://www.open3d.org/docs/0.12.0/python_api/open3d.geometry.PointCloud.html) it's within the `geometry` module. Try:

```
pc = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
```

See also [this example](http://www.open3d.org/docs/0.9.0/tutorial/Basic/working_with_numpy.html) where they import `PointCloud` from the `geometry` module.

Comment: Hey @Kemp, I applied your suggestion but now I get AttributeError: module 'open3d' has no attribute 'geometry' error.

Comment: Are any of your own scripts called `open3d.py`? It could be importing that instead of the one from the installed package if so.

Comment: nope, I haven't got any scripts called open3d.py :(((

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when you build open3d from source you might encounter that error.
Try,
`o3d.geometry.PointCloud.estimate_normals(<cloud>,search_param=o3d.geometry.KDTreeSearchParamHybrid(radius=<float>,max_nn=<int>))`